# Values are not being properly assigned to a variable

Tags: c, variable-assignment

Hi everyone I was hoping i could get some help regarding a problem I've been stuck over for the past hour.As far as my understanding of the C is concerned code seems perfectly fine and should work without a hitch.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
int salary;
float net_salary;

printf("Please enter your salary.\n");
scanf("%d", &salary);

if(salary >= 2000){
    net_salary = salary - ((7/100)*salary);
    printf("Your net salary is %f." ,net_salary);
}
else if(salary >= 10000 && salary < 20000){
    net_salary = salary - 1000;
    printf("Your net salary is %f.",net_salary);
}
```

}

The above code returns the following result when I enter 12000 gives the following result.

```
Please enter your salary.
12000
Your net salary is 12000.000000.
```

and for 6000 it returns

```
Please enter your salary.
6000
Your net salary is 6000.000000.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Edit:- The code takes a user input as the salary and if the salary is greater than 2000 and less than 10000 then 7% of it is deducted for salaries between 10000 and 20000 , 1000 is deducted. The resultant net salary is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `7/100` is an integer division. It will truncate the result to `0`.

If you want a `float` result, then use `7.0f / 100.0f`. Or plain `0.07f`.

Comment: Hey thanks alot worked perfectly, I'll be careful in the future.